# Firebase - synchronous call to validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firebase, firebase-security

I have some jquery UI code that triggers a series of updates to firebase.

I want to cancel the jquery event processing if the first update fails.

```
function fbpush(ele)
// handler called by jquery event, push an HTML element to firebase
{   window.fb.child($(ele).attr("id")).set
    (    $(ele).html()
         ,function (error) {if (error) { /* cancel propagation */ };}   
    );
    // block till firebase set returns (OK or fail)
}
```

The code is called (in this instance) so when jquery-ui sortable (linked) div is updated by a user the new html is passed to firebase where other subscribing users get the update pulled down and displayed with minimum overhead/processing (part of an experiental multi user gaming platform/framework). Firebase validation is used to ensure the update is allowable. If the updates fail, it isnt fatal, as the updater will have their screen refreshed from FB with the original HTML - but cancelling the event gives a better user experience.

```
$(document.body).on("sortupdate",".fbpush",function(event,ui) { fbpush($(this)); });
```

So really a synchronous version of the set would be perfect...

Ideas?

Comment: There is no synchronous version of `set`. But why don't you simply handle it in the callback you already have (`function (error) { ... }`)? That function gets called when Firebase has completed the update.

Comment: If the push fails firebase validation, I want to cancel the jquery event - if I dont block while the validation completes the jquery event may have already completed before I know the result.

Comment: This sounds like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Can you share the use case? There's likely a much better solution than making async things behave synchronously.

Comment: I don't want to duplicate validation client and server side - so want to rely on firebase (serverside) validation only. Let the client attempt its updates, but cancel the update if it fails validation. - by cancelling the event I don't have to worry about any other handlers that may have been attached to the event.

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes fbpush? I think we're just having a hard time trying to understand your use-case.

Comment: I have added that info to the question - but I am working on several approaches already - if sync isnt possibe, I will drop this one and continue with the others.